# Qt Scanning Wi-Fi by QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, wifi, qnetworkaccessmanager

Welcome I have a problem with scanning Wi-Fi to get all available connecting in Wi-Fi. I have writed so far this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkSession>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
    QNetworkConfiguration::StateFlags flags;

    int count = QNetworkConfiguration::Active;

   qDebug() << "Amount available connect in Wi-Fi :" << count;

   qDebug() << ncm.allConfigurations(flags = 0);

   return a.exec();

}
```

I have a problem with shows allConfigurations. I have read documentation 
[Qt Network Configuration Manager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html)
but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I would like to get list of available device which I can connect by wifi. I have read that allConfigurations make it possible but I can't make it works.

Comment: function `allConfigurations` return `QList<QNetworkConfiguration> ` you can NOT qDebug it.

Comment: Okay i make you a simple app to do that.

Comment: `int count = QNetworkConfiguration::Active;` looks wrong. You are not getting the count of active device, you are storing the int value of an enum. And edit you question instead completing it by posting comments.

Comment: it is better to use native methods to get wifi network SSIDs because there is no guarantee that "QNetworkConfiguration "will always return SSID of the network . If it is windows use windows library and if it is android use android wifi service through java and if it is in ios use objective c

Answer (score 5):

Scanning Wi-Fi using  [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

I use QNetworkConfigurationManager class to get all WiFi s availables and show all of them into QTreeWidget.

QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    netcfgList = ncm.allConfigurations();

[image: App Screenshot]

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WiFi
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    findTimer = new QTimer();
    findTimer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(findTimer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&MainWindow::findActiveWirelesses);
    findTimer->start();
    foundCount = 0;
    ui->treeWidgetWiFis->setColumnWidth(0,50);
    ui->treeWidgetWiFis->setColumnWidth(1,200);
    findActiveWirelesses();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::findActiveWirelesses()
{
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    netcfgList = ncm.allConfigurations();
    WiFisList.clear();
    for (auto &x : netcfgList)
    {
        if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
        {
            if(x.name() == "")
                WiFisList << "Unknown(Other Network)";
            else
                WiFisList << x.name();

            qDebug() << x.type();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<WiFisList.size(); i++)
    {
        bool exist = false;
        QTreeWidgetItem * item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        for(int j=0; j<ui->treeWidgetWiFis->topLevelItemCount(); j++)
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem *index = ui->treeWidgetWiFis->topLevelItem(j);
            QString str = index->text(1);
            if(str == WiFisList[i])
            {
                exist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!exist)
        {
            item->setTextAlignment(0,Qt::AlignVCenter);
            item->setTextAlignment(1,Qt::AlignHCenter);
            item->setText(0,QString::number(++foundCount));
            item->setText(1,WiFisList[i]);
            ui->treeWidgetWiFis->addTopLevelItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QList>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkSession>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    int foundCount;
    QNetworkConfiguration netcfg;
    QStringList WiFisList;
    QList<QNetworkConfiguration> netcfgList;

public slots:
    void findActiveWirelesses();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *findTimer;
    QStandardItemModel* listModel;
    QNetworkSession *session;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have checked for a moment this code.

Comment: @nightrayy I Update my answer.  add screenshot and explain more.

Comment: I get an error like that :/home/krzysztof/Pulpit/QT-programy/WiFi/mainwindow.cpp:16: błąd: ‘class Ui::MainWindow’ has no member named ‘treeWidgetWiFis’
     ui->treeWidgetWiFis->setColumnWidth(0,50);
         I have added QWidgetTree but it did not help

Comment: any reason to use `QTreeWidget` and not [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)?

Comment: Ok I have added treeWidget and rename him to treeWidgetWifis and window shows but in console are just 0

Comment: @nightrayy See my screenshot, it's working for me. are sure there is WiFi network available in your area ?

Comment: @Mike No reason, it's optional !

Comment: Yes I am sure. When I make sudo iwlist wlan0 scan in terminal wifi connection shows

Comment: @nightrayy  Download this simple app and run it. [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7jrm90s1vsrs5m2/WiFi.rar)