# QProcess sometimes returning empty string

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, wifi, qprocess

I have been recently trying to create a function to scan wireless networks within my program. Basically there is a "Scan" button and this function is triggered when its used.

This function is pretty simple, it just instances a QProcess which opens a shell and the following command native from macOS X is executed:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport  -s | awk -F\" \" '{ print $1 }
```

Which allows me to do a scan of he nearby wireless networks and filter the results to only show a list of their SSID.

The problem arises because when I use my Qt function, it returns me the correct SSIDs, but on most occassions, when I press the button again, the returned list is empty. Trying to debug the application I see that the QProcess command returns an empty string.

Code from my application:

```
QStringList WifiConnection::scan_macOS()
{
    QProcess* myProcess = new QProcess( this );
    QString airport = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport";
    QString command = " -s | awk -F\" \" '{ print $1 }";

    qDebug() << "Opening shell.";
    myProcess->start("sh");
    qDebug() << "Executing command: " << airport << command;
    myProcess->write(airport + command);
    myProcess->closeWriteChannel();
    myProcess->waitForFinished();
    QString info = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this and if there is any solution to not get this empty string?

EDIT:

- Qt Version used: 5.4.1
- Device: Mac Book Air (macOS)

Comment: Have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486924/qt-scanning-wi-fi-by-qnetworkaccessmanager ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we want to try avoid using the Bearer Management from Qt to do a native Wi-Fi connection wrapper for each OS for a future update to newer versions of Qt.

Comment: Considering there is a *waitForStarted()* method available for QProcess objects, I would assume that its possible that in your case, the *sh* program is not started and doesnt accept standard input yet. Try with **myProcess->waitForStarted();** before calling write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the issue happens because the airport manager in macOS is already busy with another action (scan for example).

This can happen for some reasons:

- Another app is controlling the airport application.
- The use of **QNetworkConfigurationManager** which performs a automatic wireless scan every 10 seconds.
- Location is enabled in your laptop, which in some OS versions causes periodical scans.

What I did to avoid getting an empty answer was adding `myProcess->waitForFinished();` as @markus-nm suggested in a comment, and ensured the result was not empty with `if (!info.isEmpty())`.