# How to detect and connect wifi display from C++ code

Tags: c++, windows

Windows 10 has a very nice feature that let you to connect to a wifi external display like a smart TV and use it as an external monitor. I'd like to make this function available from my application developed in C++ with QT. I cannot use the Windows UI to access this feature because my application is an embedded one and hides completely the Windows OS. Is there an API which can be used to access this feature by code?

Comment: Is this what you need? [Qt Scanning Wi-Fi by QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486924/qt-scanning-wi-fi-by-qnetworkaccessmanager)

Comment: You want to use a windows 10 specific feature, without using the specific windows 10 feature? Seems like a bad approach.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I try to answer... I don't just want to search and connect to WiFi networks (I already do that) I'd like to stream my monitor to it too. For the second comment maybe I didn't explain correctly my purpose: I cannot use the access to the feature that Windows gives to the users by Windows UI... I need to develop a UI to access this features on my own because my application is launched in place of the Windows shell (it's a kiosk app)... So I need to access some API to list the compatible evices and than connect to them to stream what is displayed on the screen.